# Dispatching event from advancedDatagrid to its item renderer component

Tags: apache-flex, events, event-handling, itemrenderer, advanceddatagrid

I Need to catch an event in itemrenderer component dispatched from its parent i.e an advanced datagrid. How could i achieve it. Please suggest me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement IDropInListItemRenderer with your ItemRenderer. Its property listData has a property owner which would be your AdvancedDataGrid. You could subscribe to the events of listData's owner in listData setter function.

Answer (score 0):

Item renderer has `owner` property, which should be data grid, use it to add listener.